# Why is my form returning a Reference Error: google is undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I've been developing an HTML form that submits to a Google Apps Script, and then the script does a number of things to create folders, pdfs, fill in a spreadsheet and whatnot. However, I believe I was running into a custom function runTime limitation of 30seconds. So I looked into it further, and found that you can call the apps Script function on the client-side. However, no matter what I've done, I keep on getting a 'Reference Error: google is undefined' error

While the submission is working correctly, I'm having a hard time calling any of the server-side functions from the client-side. Each time, the initial doPost() function correctly executes, but the latter functions return an error in the console stating that there is a "ReferenceError: google is not defined". I've spent hours researching, and probably way too much time with ChatGPT.

I've moved the scripts down to right before the  tag, I've added and removed the async defer attributes,  and yet I'm still getting the error. Am I calling the appsScript incorrectly, or sourcing it incorrectly?

Sorry if this is a super simple problem, I'm pretty new to this, and flying by the seat of my pants.

I've attached the relevant HTML code below:

```
'<script async defer src="Webapp-URL-here"></script>
<script async defer>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        const form = document.getElementById('Form-ID-here');
        form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            const data = new FormData(form);

            data.forEach((value, key) => {
                console.log(key, value);
            })

            const action = e.target.action;
            fetch(action, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: data
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}');                    }
                return response.text();
            })
            .then((data) => google.script.run.createCustomFolder(data))
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error during form submission:', error);
                });
            })
        })
</script>`
```

Comment: The error means what it says: the identifier `google` that appears in your code is not defined anywhere inside the JavaScript context on your page. Browsers don't know what `google` means unless you import code that defines it.

Comment: Are you using HTMLService to build and display your form?  That's where `google` is defined.

Comment: Nope, I'm not... I have it embedded with another site builder, so I should relocate my html to another google Apps script file? And then, can I just embed the same link directly into the site builder I was using before?

Comment: About `I have it embedded with another site builder`, if ou want to put your showing HTML into outside of Google Apps Script project and you want to access Google Apps Script, in this case, it is required to request Web Apps with fetch API. By the way, can I ask you about the relationship between `Webapp-URL-here` and `createCustomFolder` of `google.script.run.createCustomFolder(data)`?

Comment: Ah, okay... And Webapp-URL-here is a placeholder for the deployment URL when I deploy it as a WebApp in Apps Script, and createCustomFolder is a custom function that's within the Apps Script code. So, could I call the backend function with another fetch block?